# How to specify the Visual Studio platform toolset during install

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, vcpkg

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and I need to install several libraries using a specific platform toolset.

Right now I have three platform toolsets intalled: `Visual Studio 2015 (v140)`, `Visual Studio 2017 (v141)` and `Visual Studio 2019 (v142)`.

Is there a way to specify the platform toolset dirung the installation of a package? By default vcpkg is using the latest tools (v142 in my case).

This works great:

> vcpkg install grpc:x86-windows-static

I tried this:

> vcpkg install grpc:x86-windows-static-v141

which doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You will probably need to create a new triplet the existing files are **%vcpkgroot%\vcpkg\triplet**s and use them as reference. You will probably need to set the following cmake set from the vcpkg readme about [tirplets](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/triplets.md#vcpkg_visual_studio_path)